# Application To Set Default Calendar Reminder

Tags: calendar, alarm

We know that Google Calendar application has a way to set reminder / alarm. However, there are times (well, almost every time) when I forgot to set reminder and I missed it :(.

My question is, is there an application (preferably free, as I don't have CC and Google's Android market doesn't support PayPal, yet) that can help me set defult reminder for every event I have? So that if I forgot to set it on calendar application, this application will help me remind events.

I've already test `Calendar Snooze`. But, it require me to set an alarm first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an app: [Business Calendar Beta](http://www.appbrain.com/app/business-calendar-beta/netgenius.bizcal) (free) that support default reminder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My native calendar app on my Droid 1 running 2.2 has an option to set the default reminder time in the app settings. All my events have this reminder unless I specify otherwise.  You can also set this on the web calendar.

Comment: My native calendar app on galaxy 551 running 2.2 too. But, I can't find the option :(

Comment: @silent: Menu | More | Settings | Default reminder time

Comment: my native app doesn't have 'More' :(

Answer (score 1):

You can put a default notification in the web google calendar.
(Settings -> calendars -> Notifications).

If you select "popup notification", a notification (with sound) will be launch on your phone too.

All events created in this calendar will have this default notification.

Comment: This changes the notification default for events created on the website, but not for events created on the phone.